# Trennbares Verb bei Dass-Nutzung

Tags: separable-verb, subordinate-clause

Should it be:

> Ich denke, dass wenn ich früher *aufstehe*, …

or

> Ich denke, dass wenn ich früher *stehe auf*, … ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aufstehe (first one) is correct